# Quick question about real analysis (limits)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $x,y \in \Bbb R$

Is the following correct?

$\forall \epsilon >0$ we have $|x-y|< \epsilon \iff x=y$

Comment: Try $x=1$, $y=2$.

Comment: You'll get $x \leq y$.

Comment: Forgot the absolute, sorry

Comment: The $\impliedby$ direction is obvious. For the $\implies$ direction, try a proof by contradiction. WLOG suppose $x < y$, write $y = x + \varepsilon_0$ for some $\varepsilon_0 > 0$...

Comment: This is a simple property of order relations. The result holds when the symbols used are rational numbers. Nothing specific from real analysis is needed and result should be treated as a basic result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\forall \epsilon>0) \;\;\;\; |x-y| <\epsilon $$

$$\implies (\forall n\in\mathbb N)\;\; \;\; |x-y|<\frac {1}{n+1} $$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}|x-y|\le 0$$
$$\implies  |x-y|=0$$

$\implies x=y $.

> or
>   assume $x\ne y $ and take $\epsilon=\frac {|x-y|}{2} $.

Answer (score 2):

This is true in the [usual axiomatic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers) of real numbers where it is a consequence of the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Archimedean_property_of_the_real_numbers) that implies the  non-existence of nonzero infinitesimal real numbers.